# System Requirements Lab does not run

Tags: windows-7, gaming

I recently reinstalled Windows 7 on a Dell Vostro V131 laptop and downloaded the **System Requirements Lab** (detection.exe) from the ["Can you run it" website](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri).

When trying to run the program, it starts up fine but says:

> System Error. 
>   We're sorry but an error occurred and we can't continue.
>   Error: Unknown.

See the error in the image of the dialogue box below. No other information is given. I've tried restarting my machine and re-downloading the program, but nothing is different. And I can't seem to find a way to contact System Requirements Lab for help. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is your machine connected to a proxy by chance?

Comment: No it is not connected to a proxy.

Comment: The only other explanation is that your security software is blocking the application from connecting to the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure I even have any security software. As I said in the question, I recently did a full wipe of my system and reinstalled the operating system, so I can't think of anything that would be blocking it. How might I get around this if this was the case?

Comment: You should verify if you have security software installed (Windows Firewall counts as security software that could block this application from accessing the internet) and update your question.